# Android synchronization starts even when network is down

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have settuped Account and Sync services correctly but I have noticed that `onPerformSync` from my `SyncAdapter` launched even after I had turned off my Wi-Fi(I havent any other connections for sure).

Synchronization process I start from my `ContentProvider`:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(a, PROVIDER_NAME, new Bundle());
```

I am sure it is not correct behaviour but can't understand where the reason could be.

Thanks in advance!

---

Seems reproduced only on

> Device: Dropad OS: 2.3.1 Core: 2.6.35.7 Build: MID Serials 2.3.1
>   GINGERBREAD 20110622.181037